Aachman requires initiation?
As nama japa does not require initiation based on the community source.
Can aachman can be added before nama japa if the aspirant is not initiated?

Even Shudras can perform Achaman so it doesn't require initiation as I guess.

हृद्गाभिः पूयते विप्रः कण्ठगाभिस्तु भूमिपः ।  वैश्योऽद्भिः
प्राशिताभिस्तु शूद्रः स्पृष्टाभिरन्ततः ॥ ६२ ॥
The Brāhmaṇa is purified by the water reaching the heart; the Kṣatriya
by that reaching the throat; the Vaiśya by water that is just sipped,
and the Śūdra by what is touched with the end.
[Manusmriti Ch 2 Sh 62]

Medatithi writes:

The Śūdra by what is touched with the end;’—‘anṭataḥ’ stands for
‘antena’; the ‘tasil’ affix having the force of the instrumental,
according to the Vārtika on Pāṇini, 5. 4. 44. The term ‘end’ (anta)
means proximity; e.g., the phrase ‘udakānta’ means ‘near water’. It
also means a part; e.g., in such expressions as ‘vastrānta,’
‘vasanānta’ and the like. With both these significations the term
‘end’ (being a relative term) stands in need of a correlative;
whenever it is used, one always wants to know—‘near what ’ or ‘part of
what.’ Now in the present case, the water-sipping has been laid down
for the other castes as to he done with certain parts of the hand and
the lips and the tongue; and it is the ‘end’ of these that is meant.
It cannot mean mere ‘proxi mity’; because the ‘water-sipping’
prescribed cannot he accomplished by mere proximity. Then again, the
‘touch’ (of the water with the tongue and lips) would involve sipping
(which has been laid down for the Vaiśya); for one is sure to feel the
taste of that which is touched with the tongue and lips. Hence the
conclusion appears to he that the quantity of water sufficient for the
Śūdra is just a little less in quantity than that for the Vaiśya;
e.g., while for the Vaiśya the water should touch the root of the
tongue, for the Śūdra it should touch only its tip.


Too much complexity, I feel guru’s guidance is better than following alone. Thanks for your valuable insights.
